# My iMac suddenly crashed when I turned off my Bluetooth headset. Why?

Tags: mac, bluetooth, crash

My iMac running OSX 10.8.2 suddenly turned itself off. It was a hard reset. It said that an error had occurred. Basically the equivalent of a Windows 'blue screen.' It happened when I turned off my Bluetooth headset.

It booted back up. Everything appears normal. What went wrong? What action can I take to prevent this from happening again? Fortunately I had saved my work. Here's the error information:

---

Interval Since Last Panic Report:  3024920 sec
Panics Since Last Report:          1
Anonymous UUID:                    CDD7F4FD-E1AC-1148-BD8E-281423DBA8B2

Wed Jan 16 16:21:58 2013
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff8009c43d5b): "a freed zone element has been modified in zone: kalloc.1024"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-2050.18.24/osfmk/kern/zalloc.c:214
Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81dc84b3b0 : 0xffffff8009c1d626 
0xffffff81dc84b420 : 0xffffff8009c43d5b 
0xffffff81dc84b460 : 0xffffff8009c435d2 
0xffffff81dc84b540 : 0xffffff8009c245ed 
0xffffff81dc84b570 : 0xffffff800a022ca2 
0xffffff81dc84b590 : 0xffffff7f8a9fe3ac 
0xffffff81dc84b6d0 : 0xffffff7f8a8d71bd 
0xffffff81dc84b800 : 0xffffff7f8a8ca9aa 
0xffffff81dc84ba00 : 0xffffff7f8a8d0a58 
0xffffff81dc84bae0 : 0xffffff7f8a8f1fb3 
0xffffff81dc84bb50 : 0xffffff7f8a8f1f2f 
0xffffff81dc84bbc0 : 0xffffff800a047d9a 
0xffffff81dc84bc20 : 0xffffff800a064b8f 
0xffffff81dc84bd70 : 0xffffff8009c981e1 
0xffffff81dc84be80 : 0xffffff8009c20aed 
0xffffff81dc84beb0 : 0xffffff8009c10448 
0xffffff81dc84bf00 : 0xffffff8009c1961b 
0xffffff81dc84bf70 : 0xffffff8009ca5b16 
0xffffff81dc84bfb0 : 0xffffff8009cced53 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily(4.0.9f33)[1C326A11-ADF7-353E-AD41-458D6A886E05]@0xffffff7f8a8bc000->0xffffff7f8a95cfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily(5.4.0)[C3094550-7F58-3933-A4F7-CD33AE83F8B9]@0xffffff7f8a415000
         com.apple.iokit.AppleBluetoothHCIControllerUSBTransport(4.0.9f33)[867D6939-4D49-3149-A1A5-380C236C8D12]@0xffffff7f8a9f2000->0xffffff7f8aa18fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily(5.4.0)[C3094550-7F58-3933-A4F7-CD33AE83F8B9]@0xffffff7f8a415000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[A35915E8-C1B0-3C0F-81DF-5515BC9002FC]@0xffffff7f8a71e000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.7.2)[B1B77B26-7984-302F-BA8E-544DD3D75E73]@0xffffff7f8a28d000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: BluetoothAudioAg

Mac OS version:
12C60

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 12.2.0: Sat Aug 25 00:48:52 PDT 2012; root:xnu-2050.18.24~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 69A5853F-375A-3EF4-9247-478FD0247333
Kernel slide:     0x0000000009a00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8009c00000
System model name: iMac12,2 (Mac-942B59F58194171B)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 155608582049924
last loaded kext at 122332985218994: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC   4.1.22 (addr 0xffffff7f8c001000, size 16384)
last unloaded kext at 122457059381097: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC 4.1.22 (addr 0xffffff7f8c001000, size 12288)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 1.8
com.apple.filesystems.afpfs 10.0
com.apple.nke.asp_tcp   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   75.15
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.12.69
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothSCOAudioDriver  4.0.9f33
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothA2DPAudioDriver 4.0.9f33
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    122
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.3.1f2
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.3.1f2
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHCIControllerUSBTransport  4.0.9f33
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics   8.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.0.9f33
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBDisplays   353
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.6.0
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.2.3
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.2d0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB    8.0.0
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.10
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.0.33
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   8.0.0
com.apple.AMDRadeonAccelerator  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.2.11
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  320.15
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.1.0
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 34
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.2.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    5.2.5
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Atheros40  600.70.23
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.2.5b3
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.6
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   5.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  1.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 196.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   4.0.39
com.apple.security.quarantine   2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   196.0.0
com.apple.security.SecureRemotePassword 1.0
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.0.9f33
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  235.28
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.3.1f2
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   86.0.3
com.apple.iokit.AppleBluetoothHCIControllerUSBTransport 4.0.9f33
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.10d0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.0.9f33
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    1.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSource  1.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio  2.9.0f6
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.8.9fc10
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.6
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.4d2
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.2.0d16
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.10d0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.3.1f2
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.3.1f2
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily 19.0.26
com.apple.kext.AMD6000Controller    8.0.0
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   8.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.2.11
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.5
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHIDKeyboard    165.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   165.5
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.5.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   1.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    1.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    1.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIUpAdapter   1.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 1.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  5.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.5.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   5.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  5.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 5.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    1.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 2.1.1
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   500.15
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.2b1
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 5.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    1.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.8.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  220
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 344
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  28.21
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  1.6
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.7.2
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: iMac12,2, BootROM IM121.0047.B1F, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 3.4 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 1.72f2
Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6970M, AMD Radeon HD 6970M, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353237334348302D4348392020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353237334348302D4348392020
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM1, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353237334348302D4348392020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM1, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353237334348302D4348392020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x168C, 0x9A), Atheros 9380: 4.0.70.23-P2P
Bluetooth: Version 4.0.9f33 10885, 2 service, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
PCI Card: Apple 57761-B0, sppci_ethernet, Thunderbolt@13,0,0
PCI Card: pci11c1,5901, sppci_ieee1394openhci, Thunderbolt@14,0,0
PCI Card: pci12d8,400e, sppci_usbopenhost, Thunderbolt@12,0,0
PCI Card: pci12d8,400e, sppci_usbopenhost, Thunderbolt@12,0,1
PCI Card: pci12d8,400f, USB Enhanced Host Controller, Thunderbolt@12,0,2
Serial ATA Device: ST31000528AS, 1 TB
Serial ATA Device: OPTIARC DVD RW AD-5690H
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514, 0xfa100000 / 3
USB Device: Keyboard Hub, apple_vendor_id, 0x1006, 0xfa120000 / 5
USB Device: Apple Keyboard, apple_vendor_id, 0x024f, 0xfa122000 / 7
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 4
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x8215, 0xfa111000 / 6
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in), apple_vendor_id, 0x850b, 0xfa200000 / 2
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0xfd120000 / 4
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader, apple_vendor_id, 0x8403, 0xfd110000 / 3
USB Device: hub_device, apple_vendor_id, 0x9127, 0x40100000 / 2
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Display), apple_vendor_id, 0x1112, 0x40150000 / 5
USB Device: Apple Thunderbolt Display, apple_vendor_id, 0x9227, 0x40170000 / 4
USB Device: Display Audio, apple_vendor_id, 0x1107, 0x40140000 / 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Kernel panic. It's nothing you did wrong. This happens occasionally. If it keeps happening, then try a different Bluetooth headset. It is probably the headset doing something that the OS wasn't expecting. It is most likely a fluke, so don't worry about it unless it is repeatable.